# How to set or get parameter to DLL library in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, variables, winapi, dllimport

I have C++ library (32bit), which I would like to load and use in C#. The DLL is working (open connection, close connection and another methods without parameters). The problem is with unexpected results of all methods of C++ library with have parameters. For example:

C++ library methods specification:

```
unsigned int WINAPI acqStatus (WORD& stat, WORD& err);
unsigned int WINAPI getStatus (double& time, TCHAR* data);
```

C# source code (extern methods):

```
    [DllImport("DllName.dll")]
    public static extern uint acqStatus(ref ushort stat, ref uint err);

    [DllImport("DllName.dll")]
    public static extern uint getStatus(ref double time, ref StringBuilder data);
```

C# first method example (returns bad value, or Im doying mistake to convert IntPtr to integer):

```
        ushort stat = 0;
        uint err = 0;

        TCPInterface.acqStatus(ref stat, ref err);

        // Result of stat is: 0x0003 or 0x0004
        // bad value 3 (expected is 0), bad value 4 (expected is 1)
```

Same situation I have with another method, with returns TCHAR*. Result is string (array of bytes). I dont know, how I get the string from data variable.

```
        double time;
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        getStatus(out time, out data);

        // Exception:
        An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

        Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I'm using 64bit Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2015. I sets my C# project to x86.

I tried to:

1. Marshal.Copy(...) or Marshal.ReadByte(...) Returns following exception:
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
2. Tried to run on x86 Windows 7: DLL result was the same (bad result).
3. Tried to change the IntPtr to byte[] I gets same exception like in Marshal.Copy()
4. Tried to change out with ref // not helped

Example 1 updated:

```
    [DllImport("DllName.dll")]
    public static unsafe extern int acqStatus(ref ushort* stat, ref uint* err);


        // Elsewhere in source code in unsafe method
        ushort* stat = 0;
        uint* err = 0;

        TCPInterface.acqStatus(ref stat, ref err);

        // I have following exception:
        An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe 
        Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: Your pinvoke are all totally wrong. You need a better understanding before you proceed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan THX, sorry, I edited the first example, but result is the same like before. Pls, check it. Thx for any idea.

Comment: It's still wrong. It's blatantly wrong. Have you made any effort at all to think about this? Just read the question that you wrote. And think.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If its blatantly wrong, please help mee to understand what exactly is bad and give mee one concrete example to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: No. It won't do you any good having us do it for you. You need to start thinking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ...but I need a solution. Ok, the first donkey mistake was the IntPtr which returns not value, but only address of value. I repaired it. But still I have same result. Why? Can you help mee understand, what im doying bad?

Comment: Think a little. Look at your edit. Even the first function is still wrong. Read it and think. And stop guessing. Stop trying the wrong calling convention. This is all documented and knowable. Why are you so set against learning?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, I dont know, if Im thinking correctly, but as I found on google the WORD& means, the result of the parameter will be address of variable, not variable value. If is it truth, how can I get in c# the variable value from the address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139421/discussion-between-steelbull-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added the changed sourcecode to the end of question. But still it not works :-(

Comment: Forget it. You are just guessing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Is the solution still blatantly bad? Do you want to help mee or not? If yes, show me right way. I need solution ASAP. THX.

Comment: The right way is to red the code to see the obvious errors and think for yourself. The first function is easy to fix. The second a little more tricky. And we don't have enough information yet.

Comment: @David Heffernan Show me please, how can I fix the first function. Thx.

Comment: You ignored the answer, which has a decent stab at it, albeit technically the return value is `int` rather than `uint`. If you ignored that, why would you listen to me?

Comment: @David Heffernan I changed the return value to int, but its not interesting, because I dont want to use it now. I need to use result of parameter "stat".

Comment: Actually I read that wrong. Sorry. Shame on me. `uint` is correct. Obviously it doesn't matter much. Of course, you should check the return values one would expect. So, Arnaud's p/invoke is perfect, given the information that we have. Why aren't you using it?

Comment: I dont know, how can I use Arnaud's p/invoke for my custom DLL, but does exist any way to read bytes from pointer "stat" to see not pointer address but content of result?

Comment: Do you know what `ref` means? And why are you ignoring the p/invoke declaration of `acqStatus` that Arnaud gave you? Do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I know, what is difference between ref and out. In this case out is enough, because "stat" is only output. I also tryed to Arnaud declaration, but as I written to Arnaud, I get following exception: On the second example, when I use Cdecl: CallingConvention.Cdecl, I get following exception: Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users.... Additional information: A call to PInvoke function

Comment: It's not `cdecl`. Arnaud's p/invokes are accurate. Pending the detail over the text encoding which only you know. And indeed the semantics of the data parameter. What is your problem with using them? I give up. You ask for help but won't listen.

Comment: Fundamentally the problem seems to be that you have no understanding of anything here. We could try to write your program for you but that would be terribly inefficient. It also would not help you. What will help you is to learn how to do this yourself. That's going to require learning some C++, and doing quite a bit of reading and experimentation.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not ask you to write an application for me! But only the way, how can I get data from "stat" variable. Reason, why I asked you about it is spend time, not lost time. I dont want to learn C++ to use one DLL one time. Sorry! Not now and not in this time, when I need to solve situation ASAP. I asked you about help, and everything, what you written is(...its blatantly wrong, ...think of yourself, ...learn C++ etc.) and you dont gived mee one concrete idea to solve it. Than stop lost time (mee and you) ...and dont write spam to stackoverflow. THX.

Comment: The answer was posted yesterday. Why are you ignoring it. You will need to learn a little c++ to understand this. Since you state that you don't want to I can only assume you want us to do all the work for you. You perhaps don't realise that's what you are asking but remember that you don't understand the subject and we do. It's clear from your use of unsafe and pointers that you don't understand this at all. Either you try to learn or we do it for you. The latter won't happen. Make some effort.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ToInt32()` and `ToString()` don't work as you expect. These methods returns the memory address of the pointer, not the retrieved value.

For the first signature, change it to:

```
[DllImport("DllName.dll")]
// WORD C++ is equivalent to ushort in C#
public static extern uint acqStatus(ref ushort stat, ref ushort err);
```

For the second it's a little bit more complicated without the exact implementation but a good try will be :

```
[DllImport("DllName.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint getStatus(ref double time, StringBuilder data);
```

Comment: The First: I change it exactly, like you, but I have same result. For ref ushort stat the result is 0x003 correct must be 0x000 and 0x004 and correct bust be 0x001 :-( The second Im trying.

Comment: On the second example, when I use Cdecl: CallingConvention.Cdecl, I get wollowing exception: Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users.... Additional information: A call to PInvoke function

Comment: You can remove the `CallingConvention` and retry. Better if you know the charset you can specify it directly

Comment: I removed Cdecl, but result is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: It's not cdecl. Stop guessing.